# Javascript regex for multiple currencies

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to fetch the currency from a string. My price can have multiple format. Let's take for example CAD vs USD. CAD will be formatted this way :

5.00$ CAD

While USD will be formatted this way

$5.00 USD

The system also support euro, and GBP. Obviously the price could be in the tousands.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt :

```
result = /^([^\$]+)\$/i.exec(price.text());
```

Comment: What erroneous inputs can you expect?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the number out? `/(\d|\.)+/`? (This is obviously a crude regex but it sounds like it'll do the job.)

Comment: The field is filled from a database string. So the validation has already been done. However the guy previously working on the project decided to put the string instead of a float for some reason. I don't have to worry about "," or special char. I only need to fetch the float number.

Comment: `var result = parseFloat(price.replace(/[^0-9\\.\\,]/g,'').replace(',','.'));` should work with most values

Comment: Oh god, now I feel like I was looking way too far! I was trying way to hard. Thanks. Feel free to post your answer @Mathletics if you want some points ;)

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it.

```
/(\d|\.)+/
```

will pull out the number.

You can also do a replace, per [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119373/javascript-regex-for-multiple-currencies/19119671#comment28271752_19119373), to clean it up:

```
price.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
```

and then `parseFloat` if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Wow - I'm not sure I understand - you only want to extract the number (thousands, wholes and decimal portions) buit not the type of currency??? what about exchange rates?? are there other columns that indicate the currency type? just seems weird...

But if the column only contains a string with the amnount and currency indicators, then `[\d.,]+` should get the number (and any trailing or leading commas or periods) - does that work for you?

Comment: Yeah, actually the DB is kinda messed up. The guy previously working with the project put a simple field that takes the string. Really weird but I have to do with it. I was trying to hard. The simple \d did the job. Thanks.

Comment: just a quick question - many European currencies use `,` as the decimal separator - does your data not have that?

Answer (score 0):

*Money* is commonly represented as an [`int`, `currency`] tuple. I'd aim towards a format like that.

Your string seems to have a bit of fluff in it. The `$` for one.

So how about:

```
var db_string = "5.00$ CAD"; // or "$5.00 USD" or "€5.00 EUR"
var clean = db_string.replace(/[0-9A-Z ]/g, ""); // removes $ . and euro etc.
var parts = clean.split(" ");
var num = parseInt(parts[0], 10); // amount as int, in cents
var cur = parts[1]; // currency: USD, CAD, EUR etc.
```